# Type declaration ..rest prop in React functional component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm really tired of searching about this subject. I can't handle with ...rest prop in functional component with typescript interface.

How can declare a ...rest prop with typescript interface or whatever.

There is an example of my simple code.

**App.tsx is here**

```
function App() {
  const handleClick = (): void => {
    console.log('Clicked!!!');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button success rounded outline className="mb-5"> //(*className throws error says: ype '{ children: (string | Element)[]; success: true; rounded: true; outline: true; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.*)
          <GoBell />
          Click Here!!
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button danger outline>
          <GoCloudDownload />
          Buy Now!
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button warning>
          <GoDatabase />
          See Deal!
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button secondary outline>
          Hide Ads!
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button primary rounded>
          Something
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Button.tsx is here**

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import className from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  primary?: boolean;
  secondary?: boolean;
  success?: boolean;
  warning?: boolean;
  danger?: boolean;
  outline?: boolean;
  rounded?: boolean;
  rest?: //What can I write here?
}

function Button({
  children,
  primary,
  secondary,
  success,
  warning,
  danger,
  outline,
  rounded,
  ...rest
}: Props) {
  const classes = className(
    rest.className, // ( *There is error says: Property 'className' does not exist on type '{ rest?: any; }'* )
    'flex items-center px-3 py-1.5 border transition',
    {
      'border-blue-500 bg-blue-500 text-white hover:bg-blue-600': primary,
      'border-gray-800 bg-gray-800 text-white hover:bg-gray-900': secondary,
      'border-green-500 bg-green-500 text-white hover:bg-green-600': success,
      'border-yellow-500 bg-yellow-500 text-white hover:bg-yellow-600': warning,
      'border-red-500 bg-red-500 text-white hover:bg-red-600': danger,
      'rounded-full': rounded,
      'bg-white': outline,
      'text-blue-500': outline && primary,
      'text-gray-800': outline && secondary,
      'text-green-500': outline && success,
      'text-yellow-500': outline && warning,
      'text-red-500': outline && danger,
    }
  );

  if (
    Number(!!primary) +
      Number(!!secondary) +
      Number(!!success) +
      Number(!!warning) +
      Number(!!danger) >
    1
  ) {
    return (
      <button className={classes}>Please select only one variation!!!</button>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button className={classes} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

I tried many things. Here is some fix I tried;

**inside the Button.tsx**

```
1)
interface Props {
  .......
  rest?: Array<any> 
}

2)
interface Props {
  .......
  rest?: [any] 
}
3)
interface Props {
  .......
  rest?: Array<{className: string}> 
}

etc..
```

Comment: `rest` is not a property that you define in your interface. Typescript automatically infers the type from the remainder properties (those you don't include in your destructure syntax).

Comment: If your goal is to add support for unspecified button/aria attributes, you can extend the `Props` interface with `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, React.AriaAttributes {}`. This will make sure that the `rest` type complies with the expected button props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an indexer property but as Chris Said it sounds a really bad idea :

```
    interface Props {
      children: ReactNode;
      primary?: boolean;
      secondary?: boolean;
      success?: boolean;
      warning?: boolean;
      danger?: boolean;
      outline?: boolean;
      rounded?: boolean;
      [p:keyof any]: any
    }
```

Why so bad?

Firstly TS Type are a minimal contract, so every typed object can have properties other than those specified by their type, generaly you can use it just after checking property existance with `in` operator.

Secondly it sounds like droping so many TS features for a tniy classname to add.

There is much better ways like adding className (OK OK I understand that it can tricky if there is tons of props to add).

Or even better, extendind Props type:

```
    import React from "react";
    
    type Props = {
      primary?: boolean;
    } & Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"], "className" | "ref">;
    
    const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>(({
        primary = false,
        ...rest
    }: Props, ref) => {
        return (
            <button className={primary ? "primary" : ""} ref={ref} {... rest} />
        );
    });
    
    export default Button;
```

`& Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"], "className" | "ref">` add to Props Type every properties of `JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"]` except `"className" | "ref"`.

`primary = false,` unsure that inside the component is `true | false`, that sounds better than `true | false | undefined`.

`React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement>((..., ref)` forward the ref param to an other element this permit the caller to access the real html button if needed.

`ref={ref} {... rest}` inside the JSX is transmiting the ref propertie and all rest properties down to the button class